# Difficulty in getting QGIS to connect with in-built GPS (COM3 NMEA port)

Tags: qgis, gps, tracking, nmea

I have a Motion J3500 rugged tablet which was upgraded last year to run Windows 10.

The tablet has a built-in GPS / broadband module (Gobi Sierra 2000).
I use QGIS (v3.2) on the tablet, with the GPS plugin installed.

I want to use the GPS to add data to my QGIS by using live tracking while out on site.

The GPS itself functions fine (see photo). When I open the GPS pane in QGIS and click connect (using 'find settings automatically'), it appears to have connected, but the GPS pane within QGIS is not showing any satellite and positioning data - just zeros.
The GPS's own window shows that the GPS is working (see photo), but this is not reflected in the corresponding pane within QGIS.

One thing I've noticed is that the GPS is outputting to the COM3 NMEA port, rather than COM5 or COM6 - and I seem unable to change this.

It could be a settings or drivers issue somewhere, does anybody have experience of this and how to fix / work around?

PS, I have used the GPS to GIS link successfully on this machine in the past, but that was before the Windows 10 upgrade from W7, and was with ArcGIS, not QGIS

[image]

Comment: I don't see the photo.

Comment: Check out [this bug report](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/13330). The issue was that "QGIS does not handle NMEA data with the prefix $GN, only with the prefix $GP."

Comment: can you switch to manual internal GPS in QGIS? GPS options >https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_gps/live_GPS_tracking.html also please upload your photo